# How to get data from td with multiple classes using jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

From the web page i'm trying to extract the data which contains following text too in which i got stuck at td with mutiple classes. i'm unable to get the data which from td of table with multiple classes.

```
<div class="Uia">
<div class="eXa Iqc">
<div class="wna fa-Lsa Ala">
<div class="Cr Aha">Contact info</div>
<div class="y4">
<table class="Mlb">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="MAa">Address</td>
<td class="QLa adr">
<div class="PHb">
<div>
1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy
Mountain View, CA 94043
United States
</div>
</div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I am trying to extract the address which is in td class="QLa adr". please help me.

```
System.out.println("ADDRESS  : " +doc.select("div.Uia > div.eXa.Iqc > div.wna.fa-Lsa.Ala > div.y4 > table[class=Mlb] > tbody > tr > td[class=QLa adr] > div").text());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to use such a complicated expression to get the classes, you can select them directly.

In addition, the `[]` syntax is for selecting attributes - as with normal CSS selectors, classes are selected by prefixing the name with `.`.

In this case, assuming your website is loaded from a String (although obviously you could load it using `connect`), to get your text you can use

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(soup);
Elements extractedClasses = doc.select(".QLa.adr");

System.out.println(extractedClasses.text());
```

This prints out

```
1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy Mountain View, CA 94043 United States
```

Comment: sorry  and thnakyou very much

Answer (score -1):

I could able to get it

```
System.out.println("ADDRESS  : " +doc.select("div.Uia > div.eXa.Iqc > div.wna.fa-Lsa.Ala > div.y4 > table[class=Mlb] > tbody > tr > td[class=QLa adr] > div").text());

System.out.println("ADDRESS  : " +doc.select("div.Uia > div.eXa.Iqc > div.wna.fa-Lsa.Ala > div.y4 > table[class=Mlb] > tbody > tr > td.QLa.adr > div").text());
```